# How to migrate Pervasive database to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have a database that runs on Pervasive Control Center Version 11.30.051.000.
I want to copy that entire database to a SQL server database bs I dont want to use Pervasive anymore.

Comment: you'd have to go into a bit more detail about your actual problem. I'm not sure how you expect anyone to guess what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like the "[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)" to copy the data.  You might have to change data types as there are data types supported by Pervasive PSQL that aren't supported by SQL Server (and vice versa).

Once you copy the data, you might need to re-write your application to call the SQL Server database instead of the Pervasive database.